How to access Jenkins system configuration variables in an Active Choice Parameter Groovy script?
I have a Jenkins system configuration variable named staging_branch that changes dynamically; it represents a branch name in a multi-branch pipeline.
I want to access it in an Active Choice parameter Groovy script and tried this in the Jenkins script console
import hudson.model.*

FOLDER = "myMultiBranchPipeline"

def getBuildJobs() {
  def buildJobs = []

  Hudson.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {
  if (it.fullName.contains(FOLDER) && it.name.contains(env.staging_branch})) {
          buildJobs.add(it.name.replace("%2F", "/"))
      }
  }
  return buildJobs
}

println getBuildJobs()

or even simply:
import hudson.model.*

FOLDER = "myMultiBranchPipeline"

def getBuildJobs() {
  return [env.staging_branch]
}

println getBuildJobs()


But I get:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: env for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:310

This works in a Jenkinsfile pipeline. How can I access System configuration variables in this case?
UPDATE
I was able to make this work in the Script Console where I get a value. But it doesn't work in the Active Choice Parameter script, that is, the script doesn't return an exception, but I don't get a value.
import Hudson.model.*

List<String> getBuildJobs() {
  def globalNodeProperties = Hudson.instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
  def envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
  Map<String, String> envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()
  def jobs = []
  for (v in envVars) {
    if(v.key.equals("staging_branch")) {
      jobs.add(v.value)
      break
     }
  }
  return jobs
}
getBuildJobs()

It seems like, this doesn't work in the Active Choice Parameter script.
  def globalNodeProperties = Hudson.instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()

If I comment it out (along with the 2 lines following it and the for{} loop), and just hard-code def jobs = ["release/myBranch"] I see that value.

Does return [staging_branch] work?

@tim_yates, I tried that too and it didn't work.

try to wrap your code with try-catch: try { return getBuildJobs() } catch(e){ return [ e.toString() ] }

I got this to work after finding Jenkins Environment Parameters with groovy.
import hudson.EnvVars;
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty;
import hudson.slaves.NodeProperty;
import hudson.slaves.NodePropertyDescriptor;
import hudson.util.DescribableList;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;

List<String> getBuildJobs() {
  Jenkins instance = Jenkins.getInstance();

  DescribableList<NodeProperty<?>, NodePropertyDescriptor> globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties();
  List<EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty> envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class);

  EnvVars envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()

  def jobs = []
  for (v in envVars) {
    if(v.key.equals("staging_branch")) {
      jobs.add(v.value)
      break
     }
  }
  return jobs
}
getBuildJobs()

